# Does official Facebook app store some open data like access token and etc

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk, fbconnect

I would like to get access to the current user in official Facebook and pass user credentials to my app from official Facebook app to get current session.

Is this possible to do?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/ios/v2.2

Thats all you need

Comment: thanks for the answer, and this will return for me current logged in user from the official facebook app. Right?

Comment: Should do so, but please read the documentation, everything is documented very well.

Comment: it every time opens web view dialog, but my official Facebook app has logged in user

Comment: If you have a website that uses Facebook login there is no way for it to know that someone have the Facebook app installed and is logged in there.